# SherlockActionBar: hiding it inside a fragement

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I'm using the SherlockActionBar in an activity that calls a fragment.
I create the bar when right before creating the fragment, so I don't see the bar in the activity, just in the fragment.

But, the problem is that when I press the back button, the bar is there, and I don't know how to hide it (if I can).

Is there any way to do this, or another workaround?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

easy stuff: `getSupportActionBar().hide();`